# Setting TabControl Alignment Properties. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do like what you can see on the image below:

[image]

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. In my Form I added a `TabControl` 
and set its `Alignment` properties to `Bottom`. But as you can see in the image below, It seems there's something wrong in the display. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do it with the standard Tab control.

Try [Tab Control with Correct Bottom Theming in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/ThemedBottomTabNET.aspx) from codeproject.com.